# How to create an embedded Demo from GitHub Repository in jsFiddle?

Tags: github, jsfiddle

According to the jsFiddle documentation [Display Demo from GitHub Repository](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/github_read.html) it is easy to include a HTML Demo hosted on Github using jsFiddle.

jsFiddle allows to embed a jsFiddle into your own web page [Embedding the fiddle](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/embedding.html).

Now what I want is to host my demo files at Github and to use them by an embedded jsFiddle in my own web page (i.e. combination of both jFiddle features).

Is that possible using jsFiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

I think jsFiddle is just js code on jsfiddle webpage, so it can not embed to your page.